# Why aren't the cookies deleted?

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to unset the cookies, I had earlier set as:

```
    setcookie(session_name(),$sessionID,time() + 30*24*3600,'/');
    setcookie('UserID',$result[0]['UserID'],time() + 30*24*3600,'/');
    setcookie('UType',$result[0]['UType'],time() + 30*24*3600,'/');
    setcookie('Username',$Username,time() + 30*24*3600,'/');
```

Logout File:

```
function unsetCookie() {
    foreach($_COOKIE as $key => $value) {
        // $_COOKIE[$key] contains the cookie name as expected
        setcookie($_COOKIE[$key],'',time()-(40*24*3600),'/');
    }
}

unsetCookie();
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('Location: '.$loginPage);
exit();
```

But after the redirect in the logout file, `cookies` are still not deleted. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: @Marged The loop has the correct values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$_COOKIE[$key]` contains the value of your cookie, not the key as that is `$key`.

So you would need:

```
setcookie($key,'',time()-(40*24*3600),'/');
```

Comment: @SuhailGupta  Ah, I see: "The loop has the correct values" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Set the value to "" and the expiry date to yesterday (or any date in the past)

Try this code like that :-

```
setcookie("UserID", "", time()-(40*24*3600));
setcookie("UType", "", time()-(40*24*3600));
setcookie("Username", "", time()-(40*24*3600));
```